# How to sort alphabetically then numerically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In apache spark I'm looking to sort first lexicographically then numerically. I tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
lines = sc.textFile(...)

    bSorted = wordsRDD.sortBy(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]),ascending=False)
```

Here is the output that comes back:

```
list 1948
de 1684
new 1077
school 1065
county 1020
```

Expected output:

```
  county 1020
    de 1684
    list 1948
    new 1077
    school 1065
```

Comment: Can you provide the source data? Also what is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: Have updated the question. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could do Something like this.. I don't know how your source data looks but I am considering it to values as you are showing in the Question.
You could read it using textFile function as you are doing then you could convert that to a dataframe with two columns and do sorting on the columns and finally you can combine both the columns to have a single column if you want as per your output requirement.

//content of the input file that I am reading

[image]

```
//Code
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("<path>")
case class Test(alphabet:String,number:Integer)
val df= rdd.map( x => x.split(" ") ).map( x=> Test(x(0),x(1).toInt) ).toDF()
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.orderBy("alphabet","number")
val df2 = df1.withColumn("Text", concat_ws(" ",$"alphabet",$"number")).drop("alphabet","number")
```

You can see the output as below:

[image]